# Object gets loaded as a list using pickle module in python 3.7

Tags: python, list, object, save, pickle

I'm trying to use pickle to save and load an object, but it won't load properly. It gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): line 161, in <module> main()
 line 28, in main print(tama.__dict__)
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

This is part of my code:

```
import pickle


class Tamagotchi:
    def __init__(self, size, color, previous_actions):
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.previous_actions = previous_actions

    def change_size(self, int):
        self.size += int


def main():

    with open('save_file.txt', 'rb') as file:
        tama = pickle.load(file)

    print(tama.__dict__)


def quit(root, tama):
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Avsluta", "Vill du avsluta?"):

        with open('save_file.txt', 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump([tama], file, protocol=2)

        root.destroy()
```

I added a `print(tama.__dict__)` right before the pickle.dump() call and it printed:

```
{'size': 60, 'color': 'yellow', 'previous_actions': ['Tenta', 'Festa']}.
```

And the save_file get altered when I use pickle.dump()

So I think it gets saved properly, with the right attributes. And I think I can load it, but it gets loaded as a list or something?

Comment: `pickle.dump([tama], ...)` You're dumping a list. `[tama]` is a list.  Why would you expect the saved contents to **not** be a list?

Comment: What john is saying, is that you should do `pickle.dump(tama, open('tama.dump', 'wb'))` if you want to save the tama object as it is. And `pickle` doesn't save to a clear text format, it saves in a binary/memory dump way. If you want to dump object in a text format, you have to do it in a differenet way. And some classes won't be pickable because the state won't be saved.

Comment: @JohnGordon aaha, thank you! I completely missed that. Now it's working :)